# Creating Wiki Pages through code or CAML

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We are trying to create a site definition that includes a wiki page.

Basically we are trying to figure out how to replicate the same process that happens when a user chooses to create a new page in a blank site, and the system says something along the lines of:

"In order to create wiki pages on this site, there must be a default wiki page library and site assets library. Would you like to create those document libraries now?"

When the user chooses yes, the system provisions those libraries as well as a few "howto" wiki pages.

If anyone knows how to trigger that roll-out though code or CAML, we would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

use the Enterprise Wiki Template for creating the site?

use webtemplates instead of site definition though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the libraries, and not the default content, you can use [web.Lists.EnsureSitePagesLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistcollection.ensuresitepageslibrary(v=office.14).aspx) and [web.Lists.EnsureSiteAssetsLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistcollection.ensuresiteassetslibrary(v=office.14).aspx).